# На пользу ли задавать вопросы (ответов на которые сходу не видно на SOru), не поискав вне SOru?

Tags: обсуждение

Например, есть интересный вопрос, возможно, в данный момент не актуальный. Сходу не видно, чтобы на него были ответы на SOru. На пользу ли будет задавать такой вопрос здесь, не поискав вне этого сайта? <strike>Или даже если при первом запросе ответ можно легко найти в какой-нибудь статье на поверхности, но не на этом сайте?</strike>

Comment: Для начала поищите на SOru, чтобы удостовериться, что его не задавали ранее. Если его нет, а Вы готовы грамотно и развёрнуто на него ответить, то я считаю, что стоит. В остальных случаях - нет.

Comment: @nomnoms12, а если я не хочу отвечать? (только спросить)

Comment: @nomnoms12, тут вопрос скорее о том, можно ли спрашивать, не поискав в другом месте. То есть, не знаю, может есть ответы в других местах, может их там нету. Просто, спросить, только посмотрев есть ли такой вопрос на SOru?

Comment: Вы же сами сказали, что `ответ можно легко найти в какой-нибудь статье на поверхности`. Исходя из этого, я предполагаю, что Вы знаете ответ. Зачем же тогда спрашивать у сообщества? Лично я проголосовал бы за закрытие. Прежде чем спрашивать и тратить время экспертов, Вы должны предпринять какие-либо действия для поиска ответа. Как минимум, проанализировать проблему и прочитать документацию.

Comment: Я зайду с другой стороны. Может ли что-то опередить выпуск нового `framework`'а для `Js` (Ba Dum Tss). В общем, SO не заменяет документацию. Если бы все задавали вопросы, основываясь только на информации, уже имеющейся на SO, то прогресс бы остановился... Я против, считаю это _вредоносным шумом_ (если Вы сами не готовы ответить)

Comment: @nomnoms12, например, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1012801/185885